# How to create accessibilityFrame different from view's bounds?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I actually know how to do this, but the way in which I'm doing it leads me to my two real questions. First, I'm changing this frame in a UIButton subclass like this:

```
- (CGRect)accessibilityFrame {
    CGRect rect = [self.superview convertRect:self.frame toView:nil];
    rect.size.width *= 5;
    return rect;
}
```

If I omit the first line of this method, then the accessibility frame for this button appears in the absolute upper-left corner of the screen, regardless of its original position. All of the code samples I've found for overriding the accessibility frame use some variant of coordinate conversion, but I'm not at all understanding why. Why can't this property be treated in the same coordinate system as view frames, since this would make modifying the accessibility frame immensely more simple?

My second question relates to how this accessibility frame actually functions with VoiceOver turned on. When I modify the accessibility frame in this manner, the focus rectangle becomes larger as expected. Unfortunately, this effect appears to be purely cosmetic. Even though the focus rectangle is now much larger than the button itself, I can still only apply the focus to the button by tapping within the button bounds proper; if I tap inside the focus rectangle but outside of the button itself, nothing happens. This is a big problem for me because I'm trying to expand the "virtual" size of some controls that are so small that they're very difficult to actually tap unless you can see them. I'm not understanding at all the point of making the focus rectangle only cosmetically bigger, if sight-impaired users can't see it anyway.

**Edit:** adding this bit does the trick:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint newPoint = [self.superview convertPoint:point toView:nil];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.accessibilityFrame, newPoint);
}
```

I would still love to know why something like this is even necessary.

**Edit 2:** the code above only works in special cases (inside multiple nested sub-views). A more general solution is:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint newPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:nil];
    return CGRectContainsPoint(self.accessibilityFrame, newPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accessibility frame is specified in screen coordinates ([see documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008786-CH1-SW12)).

The conversion

```
-[UIView convertRect:toView:]
```

converts view coordinates to window coordinates if toView is nil.

To be 100% correct, an additional conversion from window to screen coordinates using

```
-[UIWindow convertPoint:toWindow:]
```

(again, with a nil toWindow) would be needed.

Now, you probably already know that you need to double-tap within the VoiceOver cursor in order to trigger the button's action. By default, the double-tap hits at the center of the accessibility frame. However, if the center of your modified accessibility frame is not on your button, nothing will happen. Conveniently, the `accessibilityActivationPoint` method lets you put that center elsewhere (e.g. right onto your button's actual center). Again, don't forget to convert to screen coordinates.

One thing to consider before you run off making huge accessibility frames: If you have really tiny buttons, they might be difficult to hit for normal users too. Consider making them (or at least the area where they respond to touches) larger. [Apple recommends](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Characteristics/Characteristics.html) at least 44 x 44 points.

Comment: I know about accessibilityActivationPoint. My problem is not with what happens when you double-tap. My problem is that I want a single tap anywhere within the bounds of the expanded `accessibilityFrame` to move the VoiceOver cursor to that button. But that doesn't seem to be how accessibilityFrame works, unless (hopefully) I'm just missing an obvious setting or something. In my app, even with the enlarged accessibilityFrame, the button still only gets the cursor if I tap within the bounds of the button itself.

Comment: I really hope I'm missing something, because if the accessibilityFrame only affects where the cursor is drawn, and doesn't affect whether the control gets the focus, then what good is it for blind people?

Comment: Also, I didn't design this app. I'm retrofitting accessibility to it. The tiny buttons are incredibly difficult for anybody to hit, but I can't change them without going through a lengthy bureaucratic process.

Comment: If you can make the accessibility frame larger, can't you also make the area where the buttons respond to touches larger (not the actual button graphics)?

If that is not an option, you can always have a superview containing the buttons return custom accessibility elements (`accessibilityElementCount`, `accessibilityElementAtIndex`, `indexOfAccessibilityElement`). Give these elements descriptions and labels matching the buttons, larger accessibility frames, and put their accessibilityActivationPoints at the centers of the actual buttons.

Comment: I guess I could do that, but I'm still not understanding why this would be necessary. What is the point of the accessibilityFrame if it's purely cosmetic?

Comment: The accessibilityFrame and accessibilityActivationPoint are used primarily for custom accessibility elements, not for subclasses of UIView. As I understand, accessibilityFrame is simply not intended for changing the area where a UIButton responds to touches triggering the VoiceOver cursor. What's wrong with simply overriding `pointInside:withEvent:`? You'd solve the issue of the tiny buttons for all your users, not just for disabled users.

Comment: Just a bit more background: On OS X, there's a special method that's exposed for accessibility hit testing `accessibilityHitTest:`. On iOS, that seems to be done in a private category of `UIView`, which relies on `pointInside:withEvent:` to determine whether to call `accessibilityFrame` at all (you can easily see that when setting breakpoints in these methods). I'd go the `pointInside:withEvent:` route for now, and file an enhancement request with Apple if you do see the need for distinct areas triggering regular touch actions and the VoiceOver cursor on UIButtons.

Comment: Thanks - overriding `pointInside:withEvent:` was exactly what I needed.

Comment: As of iOS 7, you should use `UIAccessibilityConvertFrameToScreenCoordinates(CGRect rect, UIView *view)`

Comment: You don't necessarily have to tap a button or label.  With VoiceOver (VO) on if you swipe to the right anywhere on the screen the focus for VO will go to the next element.  Swiping to the left will move to the previous element.  Double tapping even if it's off the button or label will "tap" the element with VO focus.

Comment: @Gerard : I agree with you but what is the interest of `accessibilityActivationPoint` then ? Currently, I do not know what are the use cases of this feature because the elements behavior that are inside the 'focus view' should be handled in the `accessibilityActivate`, shouldn't it ?